# Problems with integrated vuforia with 64 bit Unity

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Basically, I am having trouble playing my augmented reality app in the Unity. I have done all the right things but the app just won't play. It is a very basic app that adds a spinning cube on some real life  it sees in the real world. I know that vuforia can't handle the 64 bit Unity but i was hoping that there was either a hack or some emulator that I can use to open the unity scene with or something epic that I can't even conceive of. These are my first steps into augmented reality programming and it would help to actually see it work on my pc.

Comment: It would be better to show [mcve]..

Comment: One splution is use unity 32 bit. You can download and install it with 64bit installed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you **cannot** use 64 bit Unity with Vuforia. It may work for some features of Vuforia but you definitely will not be able to use the full functionality of Vuforia--there will always be problems.

One solution is obviously to just uninstall your current version of unity and [install a 32 bit version](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) (I would suggest **Unity 5.1.3 (32 bit)** as this is the one I know to support almost 100% of Vuforia). A note: this **will NOT** delete any Unity projects you have created, you will just need to reopen them in your new version of Unity.

Another solution is like what tim mentioned in his comment--to just have both 64bit and 32bit Unity installed of your computer. Just make sure that you stay as consistent as possible (i.e. make sure you don't accidentally open a Vuforia project with the 64bit Unity) as this will likely cause problems.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Unity 64 bit , you can try the newest version of Vuforia , **vuforia-unity-6-0-112**.It was recently released to be more compatible for unity 64 bit.You can give it a try by downloading on this link https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk. Right now im using **Unity 5.4.0f3 (64-bit**) and its working perfectly until now.